# ImageView setImageDrawable results in a blank image being drawn

Tags: android, imageview

The code in onCreate()

```
ApplicationInfo app = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getIntent().getStringExtra("app"), 0);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(app.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageDrawable(app.loadLogo(getPackageManager()));
```

The image set by the third line should draw the app icon, but instead draws blank. Just to note, the app in question is not my app, but an app on the phone. So, I've passed the ApplicationInfo directly to this activity and through the package name as it is now, so I don't think that's the issue. I've also set a dummy image in the XML and commented the third line and that image displays correctly. What am I doing wrong?

The XML

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen really strange way to set image in my opinion.
Have you tried setting it just by

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_name_here)
```

or

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_name_here)
```

?

Comment: The drawable is the icon of the app in question, which isn't mine. I don't have access to the drawable directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your "App Logo" programmatically in Image View

You can try this:

```
 Drawable icon = null;
        try
        {
            icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("packagename of your app");
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageDrawable(icon);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, it's not my app. It's another app for which the ApplicationInfo is provided.